# scanf() and clear input buffer in one function in C?

Tags: c, scanf, input-buffer

I have the following idea:

I have a function to clear the input buffer:

```
void clear_inputBuffer()
{
    char c;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Instead of writing for every input

```
scanf("%d", &selection);
clear_inputBuffer();
```

I want one function which contains both. Something like this:

```
int terminalInput(const char *format, ...) {
    int count = 0;
    va_list args;
    // Pass variable parameters
    va_start(args, format);
    count = scanf(format, args);
    va_end(args);

    clear_inputBuffer();
    return count;
}
```

The function returns 1 but "test" returns also 1 no matter what the correct input is.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int test;
    printf("number:");
    terminalInput("%d", &test);
    printf("Input: %d\n", test);

    return 0;
}
```

The terminal output:

```
$ ./a.out
number:345
Input: 1
```

Comment: `char c; while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` is an infinite loop when `char is _unsigned_ and `getchar()` returns `EOF`.  Use `int ch;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `scanf` with a `va_list`. You need to use `vscanf` instead.

Also, I feel compelled to mention that in general you should almost always avoid using `scanf`/`vscanf` entirely; it's [*notoriously*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf) hard to use correctly.  Instead, [you should read a line of input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4023895/179715) with `fgets` (or `getline` if available) and then use `sscanf` on the line.